Is it permissible, according to Shariya, to allow Hindus to visit Islamic holy sites in Medina?
On January 8, 2024, the Saudi government hosted an Indian delegation to some of the holiest sites of Islam for a visit.
Given that the Minister for Religion, Smriti Zubin Irani, is a Hindu and she didn't wear any hijab or abaya, what does Islamic shariya say about allowing and promoting non-Muslims, especially anti-Muslim Hindutva personnel, to visit these holy sites?

Is it permissible, according to Shariya, to allow Hindus to visit Islamic holy sites in Medina?

Is it permissible, according to Shariya, to allow women without hijab or abaya to visit Islamic holy sites in Medina?





Once as a tourist, the guide led me to visit a mosque, as a tourist. I felt uneasy and stayed near the door, just to have a look. It does not look right to visit other peoples holy sites. Maybe, in the case above, it may be taken as a sign of not being enemies.

To add to my comment: there was one man in that mosque doing prayer, I would not disturb him just out of curiosity, not go around taking photographs, like many tourists would do.

yes, there is nothing like that anyone should wear hijab on area of any mosque or masjidunnabi, but because they are not muslim or ahl-ul-kitab they are not pure so they are not permitted to enter the actual area of a masjid (its likely the are inside), but according to the photos you posted they did not entered that area.

i really want to know why there's three down votes
